# FluxCD on Azure AKS: Reconciler errors

Tags: kubernetes, fluxcd

I had to rerun `flux bootstrap...` on my cluster after a colleague accidentally ran `flux bootstrap...` on their new cluster using the existing branch and cluster from the same flux repo.

Running `kubectl get gitrepositories -A` has no errors -

```
flux-system flux-system ssh://git@git.group.net:7999/psmgsbb/flux.git stored artifact for revision 'master/252f6416c034bb67f06cc3e413e66704bc6b1069'
```

however I am seeing these errors now when I run `flux logs --level=error`

```
error ImagePolicy/post-processing-master-branch-policy.flux-system : Reconciler error cannot determine latest tag for policy version list argument cannot be empty

error HelmRelease/post-processing.post-processing-dev : Reconciler error previous release attempt remediation failed

error ImageRepository/post-processing-repository.flux-system : Reconciler error auth for "myacr.azurecr.io" not found in secret flux-system/psbombb-image-acr-auth-cc8mg5tk84
```

Regarding the secret above I ran:

`kubcetl get secret -n flux-system psbombb-image-acr-auth-cc8mg5tk84 -oyaml`

which gave me

```
apiVersion: v1 
data: 
.dockerconfigjson: 
   ewoJImRhdGEiOiAie1xuICBcI...<redacted>
 kind: Secret
```

which decodes to

```
"data": "{ 
    "auths": { 
      "myacr.azurecr.io": { 
         "auth": 
          "YTNlMTNlOGItYWQwNi00M2IzLTkyMjgtMjA0ZmQ2ODllMD<redacted>" 
       }
    }
 }"
```

So the ACR above `myacr.azurecr.io` does match the ACR in the secret. This error doesn't make sense to me?

```
Reconciler error auth for "myacr.azurecr.io" not found in secret flux-system/psbombb-image-acr-auth-cc8mg5tk84
```

So basically, do you know why reconcile fails now after a flux bootstrap?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `flux bootstrap...` was run accidentally on the cluster it upgraded kustomize to version 0.30.2. This was causing an issue with the formatting of the encrypted dockerconfigjson secret being written to Kubernetes.

When the dockerconfigjson contents were base64 decoded there were line feeds everywhere which seems to have caused the reconciler error whereby it could not find the ACR reference -> myacr.azurecr.io

I reverted the `gotk-components.yaml` kustomize-controller version back to the kustomize version prior to the accidental `flux boostrap...` i.e. from `v03.2` to `v022.3`.

Once the Kubernetes Secret was recreated with the correct dockerconfigjson format, reconciliation started working correctly.